# UITableViewCell custom edit view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to replace the default editing mode behaviour of the cells.

I dont want the red circle with line left accessory view to appear.

Upon entering edit mode I need it to shift the content view left & display my delete button.

*What I have so far (custom UITableViewCell) overrides:*

```
-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    /* don't call super */
//    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    _isEditing = editing;

    CGFloat newContentViewX = 0.0f;
    UIColor *newDeleteButtonColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ( _isEditing )
    {
        newContentViewX = -40.0f;
        newDeleteButtonColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if ( animated )
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^
         {
             self.contentView.x = newContentViewX; //change frame.origin.x
             _deleteButton.backgroundColor = newDeleteButtonColor;
         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self.contentView.x = newContentViewX; //change frame.origin.x
        _deleteButton.backgroundColor = newDeleteButtonColor;
    }
}

-(BOOL) editing
{
    return _isEditing;
}
```

& this is the result:
[image: setEditing:NO]
[image: setEditing:YES]

The above code works great! Until it starts scrolling & the contentview gets reset. back to the first image. The editing flag is not persisting my contentview frame changes.

I have added this line:

```
[cell setEditing:_tableView.isEditing animated:NO];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath & although it is calling & setting edit mode correctly my contentview is still in the original position & not the updated

Short youtube video explaining issue:
[Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE9d9SdbnLU)

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: You should get +1 just for making a youtube video. Very easy to understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that UITableView is "helpfully" setting up the appropriate state layout with the cell you return from cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Simplest way to deal with this is to override -layoutSubviews in your cell class.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   if (self.editing)
  {
     CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
     // do your custom layout
  }
  else
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

That should get things pretty much sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Don't tamper with the content view frame. Just create your button and set it as `editingAccessoryView` and the presentation will be done for you.

Comment: Yes, except for the fact you still get the (-) circle buttons on the left & it shifts the content view right

Comment: In `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`. You may also want to customise how and when the cell gets set into editing mode (for swipe delete).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are suffering from a side effect of how the UITableView passes the setEditting message to its child cells. The docs state that the TV sends this message to the VISIBLE cells (only). Thus, when a new/dequeued cell becomes visible it has not had the setEditting message, and thus has _editting=NO. Therefore, you need to test and set the cell's _editting=YES in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, then you should get the scrolling behaviour WITH the revealed delete button that you want.